# PHP construct an IF statement with dynamic information

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a config file containing something like this:

```
$config['sql_query_logging'] = [
    'enabled' => true,
    'exclusions' => [
        'ci_sessions', 'system_log', 'jobs_log', 'error_log'
    ]
];
```

I have written an extension to the core libraries of Code Igniter 3 that logs all `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` queries running on a system I have developed, however, there are certain tables I am not interested in logging the queries for.

Currently, my check was something like this for a single table:

```
if (
    strtolower($temp_sql) != 'select' &&
    strtolower(substr(trim($sql), 0, 11)) != 'show tables' &&
    strpos(strtolower(trim($sql)), 'ci_sessions') === false
) { 
    // ...
}
```

This works for a single table, `ci_sessions` but I want this configurable to use the config above. I then made it work by looping through the array of exclusions:

```
$contains_exclusion = 0;
if (
    strtolower($temp_sql) != 'select' &&
    strtolower(substr(trim($sql), 0, 11)) != 'show tables'
) { 
    if (is_array($exclusions) && !empty($exclusions)) {
        foreach ($exclusions as $exclusion) {
            if (strpos(strtolower(trim($sql)), $exclusion) !== false) {
                $contains_exclusion++;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($contains_exclusion == 0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

While that works, it looks very clumsy to me. Can this be improved?

Comment: _"This works for a single table, `ci_sessions`"_ - does it really, though ...? It rather looks like your code doesn't even care whether the query actually contains this as a table name, but will skip your logging when the SQL string contains `ci_sessions` _anywhere_, like somewhere in the _data_ ...?

Comment: Your point is indeed very valid. I am sure I can go ahead and tokenize the query and then improve it with additional processing, but since this is going to run on every query in the system, I wanted to get as close to "dump and forget" so that I do not put additional strain by doing unnecessary processing on every database modification. I compromised on 100% effectiveness here, as we simply want to use it in troubleshooting a troublesome bug that we are struggling to trace. In conjunction with triggers that updates a history table, and then logging queries, we can see where this pesky bug is.

Comment: Don't see much to improve then, other than that you could break out of the foreach loop, once you found the first exclusion - no real need to test all the rest of them as well at this point. For anything more "sophisticated" - like checking against an array of table names using `in_array` - you would need to actually extract the table name from the query first.

Comment: Thank you, CBroe. I was hoping there was a way to dynamically create an IF statement or something as magical as that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a little more *flexible* by having `keywords` as another option in `exclusions`. The checks for tables and exclusion of keywords can be done using some regex matches like below. Note that this isn't a *full proof* kind of filtering but should decently suffice for your debugging purposes.

Your config can look like:

```
$config['sql_query_logging'] = [
    'enabled' => true,
    'exclusions' => [
        'tables' => ['ci_sessions', 'system_log', 'jobs_log', 'error_log'],
        'keywords' => ['select', 'show tables']
    ]
];
```

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$config['sql_query_logging'] = [
    'enabled' => true,
    'exclusions' => [
        'tables' => ['ci_sessions', 'system_log', 'jobs_log', 'error_log'],
        'keywords' => ['select', 'show tables']
    ]
];

$sqls = [
    'select * from table',
    'show tables',
    'update ci_sessions set some_col = some_val',
    'update test set some_col = some_val',
    'insert into test values(23, 45)',
    'insert into ci_sessions values(1,2,3)',
    'truncate ci_sessions'
];

foreach($sqls as $sql){
    $result = array_merge(
            array_filter($config['sql_query_logging']['exclusions']['keywords'], fn($v) => preg_match('/\b'.$v.'\b/', $sql) === 1),
            array_filter($config['sql_query_logging']['exclusions']['tables'], function($table) use ($sql){
                return preg_match('/\b(from|insert into|update|join|truncate|table)\s+'.$table.'\b/', $sql) === 1;
            })
         );
    if(empty($result)){
        echo "Can log: ", $sql, PHP_EOL;
        // log here
    }else{
        echo "Cannot log: ", $sql, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/1gI2F)

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed very nice, but I know that preg_match is quite slow, and doing an array_merge and two array_filter calls on each item simply to make it more flexible is not the right way for me to approach this. I want as little overhead as possible here, flexibility is not a priority at this time. But nevertheless, thanks for the additional approach!